# Error: cannot find symbol variable Constants

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

How can import `util.Constants` in 
Android Studio 3.0.1

> Error:cannot find symbol variable Constants

`Alt+enter` said me `android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants?` But I need to import like

```
Import mypackage name.until.Constants
```

Comment: you can manually import it.

Comment: Manually import :
import mypackage name.until.Constants

and check you package name in until.Constants file if you have same package name .

Answer (score 1):

delete the Constant usage in the program.

Go to your imports section and enter

`import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants.ConstantName`

This works out.